# PHP-MYSQL encryption that is safe

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a messagging app, and I would like to encrypt the messages the safest way possible.

Currently I'm doing the following:

**chatMessages table**

```
userId   | message
---------|---------------------
1        | ENCRYPTED%withChatMasterKey%
2        | ENCRYPTED%withChatMasterKey%
...
```

**chatUsers table**

```
userId   | chatMasterKey (it is encrypted aswell with users ID's)
---------|---------------------
1        | ENCRYPTED%withUserId(1)%
2        | ENCRYPTED%withUserId(2)%
...
```

The messages are encrypted with a random masterKey that are stored in the chatUsers table where with another encryption the masterKey is encrypthed but now the key is the user's Id

**So to decrypt the messages, you have to do this in php:**

```
$message = $messagesArray[0]["message"];
$chatMasterKey = decrypt($chatUser[0]["chatMasterKey"], withKey: $userId);
$messageDecoded = decrypt($message, withkey: $chatMasterKey);
```

---

*Tthat works well, if somebody hacks the dataBase then he would not be able to read out the messages.*

But is this safe? If someone hacks the .PHP files aswell, then he will be able to figure out the method I'm using and could be able to decrypt the messages.

Is there a better way to encrypt messages?

/ for security reasons I changed some details in the post /

Comment: “for security reasons I changed some details in the post” – that seems to suggest security by obscurity, which, as we all know (repeat after me), isn’t security at all.

Comment: Assuming this is done the proper way (encrypt/decrypt only on server side, never decrypt on client, use of https for messages privacy at request level), the general schema is correct, and by design nothing can prevent someone who gets the PHP files to decrypt the messages. The server is a "safe" and has to be protected, and the PHP files that concern encryption must never be shown for your security to stand. In a more detailled way, your encryption is a bit weak, you should use salts and stuff like that

Comment: Whatsapp's whitepaper on doing the same might be of interest: https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf

Comment: It sounds like all the information needed to decrypt a message is stored within the same database…? If that is so, it's pretty pointless and will only cost a bit of CPU time to unscramble. To make this really "uncrackable" some required secret will need to be kept off the server entirely; e.g. the user's password is used in the process somewhere, and that's only kept client-side, and the final en-/decryption happens on the client's machine.

Comment: @deceze hmm seems fair, so you suggest that instead of the userId as the key to decrypt the message I should be using the user’s password in a hashed/changes form?

Comment: Again, for the data to not be decryptable, *some* information must simply not be available on your server. If all the information needed to decrypt the data is derivable from data stored within your database, then it's merely an exercise in writing the right code to do the necessary calculations. The crucial key must be something that is not permanently stored on your server and is only available when the user is logged in (and also then preferably is never send to your server).